# .net core Angular SPA application : How to design a class in C# to accommodate generic data binding at api side?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, generics, asp.net-core

We have a situation where the user performs some action on UI. Let's say selecting data from the drop-down. 
So according to selection the object being sent to Server side is going to change.

I have to keep only one controller API that will be called after value selection in the drop-down.

In future new items can be added to drop-down which in turn require Creation of new class at server side.

And properties in each class will be different.

> How do I design the class at server side and client side to
>   accommodate this generic change?

Is it optimal solution to send json string from client side and DE-serialize it in api to create the object of class?

Comment: What are you going to do with it server side once you have it?  What use case limits you to one endpoint?  Best way to handle this would be to have a class that has two properties, a TypeName property of type string, and a Data property of type object.  If you're hitting one end point, it requires a concrete class to bind to OR a parameter of type object.  I guess the bigger question is why would you want to work like this?  You're obviously not creating a RESTful API so what is the use case?

Comment: so once i get it to server side i have to bind data to respective class and perform further operations. i want to have on api action (post) to avoid duplication of code at server side.

Comment: Then I would suggest you create a service in a business layer to share code and this can be injected through DI. Have multiple API endpoints and let .net do the binding for you.  If you follow standard RESTful API practices you should be good.  Also this allows you to create unit tests against your service layer.  If you try and do everything in one function, you're going to end up with a really messy code that you won't be able to maintain.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the suggestion. if you could give link to some example that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Go take a look at this project, its the sample that microsoft use as a training aid and follows all the best practices. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb
Hope this helps